# Sumar Filas SQL con DatePart

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo este query que me trae los minutos de cada día, sin embargo yo quiero sumarlos todos, pero me regresa valora diferentes :

[image: Ejemplo de resultado]

```
SELECT  
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DateOpen) as Dias,
    SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CONVERT(Datetime,MTTA))) as Minutos 
FROM 
    GeneralReport
WHERE
    Week='4'
GROUP BY 
    GeneralReport.DateOpen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es que si quieres sumar por día de semana, debes agrupar por ese mismo dato (lo estabas haciendo por `DateOpen`)

```
SELECT  DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DateOpen) as Dias,
        Sum(DATEPART(MINUTE, CONVERT(Datetime,MTTA))) as Minutos 
        from GeneralReport
        WHERE Week='4'
        GROUP BY DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DateOpen)
```

Comment: Gracias!! no lo tome en cuenta el DATENAME